# How to checkout particular pull request

Tags: git, github

I successfully cloned a git repo

```
git clone https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart.git
```

Now I want to checkout a particular commit from this [pull request](https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart/pull/16/commits).

Here I can get the hash of the commit

https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart/tree/3536be35189b0ea9b98633a3e2abb29796727865

or, the same,

https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart/pull/16/commits/3536be35189b0ea9b98633a3e2abb29796727865

How do I checkout this commit? This command fails:

```
git checkout 3536be35189b0ea9b98633a3e2abb29796727865
fatal: reference is not a tree: 3536be35189b0ea9b98633a3e2abb29796727865
```

Comment: This commit doesnt exist at all. It exist in `stefanvitz:master`

Comment: @Smit can I checkout this commit?

Comment: You need to clone `stefanvitz:master` ! not `git clone https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart.git`

Comment: I have added answer as an explanatory for others.

Comment: @Smit you are wrong. All pulls are part of the target repo, you just have to fetch it

Comment: Thanks @Vampire . I genuinely didnt know it.

Comment: @Vampire doesnt my cincept works too right? i agree it is long way but it is not wrong. It is just illogical.

Comment: @Smit, well you are partly right. It would of course be ok to clone stefanvitz:master instead. Or you could simply add stefanvitz as a second remote and fetch his branches too. But it is wrong to say that cloning the PR target is wrong and it is wrong that the PR branches are not part of the target repo. They are just not fetched by default. You can also add a refspec to the config so that all PR branches are always fetched too. ;-)

Comment: @Vampire Thanks for the highlight! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is simple:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull/16/head
git checkout 3536be35189b0ea9b98633a3e2abb29796727865
```

You can get the number of pull request from the url:

https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart/pull/16/